# How to download a file over https using php

Tags: php, curl, https, download, security

I need to download an xml file using PHP. I am able to read the contents of file by setting following options when making a curl call to it.

```
curl_setopt ($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($http,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'XYZ');
```

As evident from above snippet I need to make VERIFYHOST as false and also need to set an explicit USERAGENT when making a call to read the file because the file is not publicly accessible and only a specific application can make call to read it (Web-Security techniques and stuff)

But how do I download the same file, I have tried `readfile`, `fopen/fpassthru`, `file_get_contents` but nothing seems to be working.
Readfile gives the error `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`

Is there a way to provide curl like options with `fopen` or `readfile`, I think that may be the easiest approach to solve this. I could not find much help in PHP documentation.

Please help.

Comment: Are you providing headers and stuff about "you" ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger Just the usual `Content-disposition` and `Content-type` headers.

Comment: You need to send headers about you: UserAgent and IP Address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach your special user-agent to the stream context.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

> Allows read-only access to files/resources via HTTP 1.0, using the HTTP GET method. A Host: header is sent with the request to handle name-based virtual hosts. **If you have configured a [user_agent string using your php.ini file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) or the stream context, it will also be included in the request**.

Example #2 from the link above:

```
<?php
ini_set('user_agent', "PHP\r\nX-MyCustomHeader: Foo");

$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com/index.php', 'r');
?>
```