# garbled xml output

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml feed using PHP:
http://trustbox.trustpilot.com/r/travelnation.co.uk.xml

Visiting this, it looks perfectly OK, but when I try

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("http://trustbox.trustpilot.com/r/netamity.com.xml");
print_r($file);
?>
```

I get

```
‹•SÁŽÓ0=/ÿ`ŒÄmœ-  ë¸ŠàèJV«••L«ŽmÙN²ý{Æi·M
...
```

How is it getting garbled? Using simplexml it wont parse it (unsurprisingly). I've tried setting headers UTF-8 headers but I think the issue is in the get_file_contents. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with any other XML feed? That would be the first thing I would check, to see which end the problem is on.

Answer (score 1):

The content looks "weird" simply because the encoding is compressed (see the HTTP header `Content-Encoding: gzip`).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: 8wYarFnod0jtLJ3U8ZDN38102fjtG+EbwJjy0tY4YTZncrz9auEcQbzt1vyiSEhq
x-amz-request-id: A60F1E6CA5437776
Date: Sun, 24 Feb 2013 18:00:45 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Sun, 24 Feb 2013 05:19:11 GMT
ETag: "64eaa6f87768aeb3ae6741ba06318cb6"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml
Content-Length: 52366
Server: AmazonS3
```

I guess what you need is to know how to read a file over HTTP; you could try [this one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529583/how-to-download-a-file-over-https-using-php).