# How to download csv file from the download link in php?

Tags: php

I want to download csv file from this link:

https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes

but this two kinds of code is also not working.

```
$url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
echo $str;
```

and

```
$table = file_get_contents('https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes');
```

Pls, tell me about why this code is not working in this link.
Thank you!

Comment: Define "not working". What *does* it do? Error messages? Timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

```php
$file_name = 'ETFList.csv';
$url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes';

function downloadFile($url, $filename)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible ; Googlebot/2.1 ; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    $file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);

    if (file_exists($filename)) {

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
        readfile($filename);
    }

}

downloadFile($url, $file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$file = 'ETFList.csv';
$url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes';

function downloadFile($url, $filename) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($data));
    readfile($data);
}

downloadFile($url,$file);
```

Comment: It is ok to download. But there is error content in the csv file, like this:            
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp64\www\test1.php on line <i>20</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
</table></font>

Answer (score 0):

There is a line in your php.ini file you can uncomment;

```
;user_agent="PHP"
```

Or you can temporarily set it in your code.

```
ini_set('user_agent', "PHP");
$table = file_get_contents('https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/etfs/etf-finder-results.aspx?download=Yes');
```

This is because you are using https. See [How to download a file over https using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529583/how-to-download-a-file-over-https-using-php)